# Right method to Use Polly C# Library to handle Exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to use Polly to handle exceptions thrown by my `WebRequest`.

This is my implementation.

```
var generalExceptionPolicy=Policy.Handle<Exception>().WaitAndRetry(2, retryAttempt => 
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)),(exception,timespan)=>{

        if(attempt++ == 2)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Activity,"No Connection Bro",ToastLength.Short).Show();


        }
    });
   var test = await generalExceptionPolicy.ExecuteAsync(()=>PostPreLogin (view.FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.mobileTextBox).Text));
```

I have got the retries working. But what I am wondering is where will I get a callback after the last attempt ? I am getting a callback in Policy definition part, where I am trying to display a `Toast`message. But that is only between the trials. I am not getting it after my last trial.

Also, my UI freezes after the last trial. Maybe becuase `ExecuteAsync` `Task` did not complete, due to the `Exception`. If that is so, what is the right approach to use Polly library ?

This is the method that I am trying to handle with Polly

```
public  async Task<string> PostPreLogin(string userName)
    {
        var preloginvalue = await Account.PreLoginPost (userName);
        return preloginvalue;

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It is easy, basically you need to define the policy and passing the call back later is just as simple . Check [this article which describes](https://doumer.me/consume-rest-apis-in-your-app-in-a-resilient-way-with-polly-and-xamarin-forms/) how to accomplish exactly what you want in details.

Basically, you can define your policy as follows :

```
async Task<HttpResponseMessage> QueryCurrencyServiceWithRetryPolicy(Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> action)
    {
        int numberOfTimesToRetry = 7;
        int retryMultiple = 2;

        //Handle HttpRequestException when it occures
        var response = await Policy.Handle<HttpRequestException>(ex =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Request failed due to connectivity issues.");
            return true;
        })

        //wait for a given number of seconds which increases after each retry
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(numberOfTimesToRetry, retryCount => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(retryCount * retryMultiple))

        //After the retry, Execute the appropriate set of instructions
        .ExecuteAsync(async () => await action());

        //Return the response message gotten from the http client call.
        return response;
    }
```

And you can pass the callback as follows:

```
var response = await QueryCurrencyServiceWithRetryPolicy(() => _httpClient.GetAsync(ALL_CURRENCIES_URL));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are after is `ExecuteAndCapture` instead of `Execute`:

```
generalExceptionPolicy.ExecuteAndCapture(() => DoSomething());
```

[Check this out](https://github.com/michael-wolfenden/Polly#post-execution-steps) for more details.